# Can I have multiple line text in the same list item?

Tags: trello

I want to have a bulleted list where some items are multiple lines (the child lines would show up indented)

- testing
- multilineworks? 
   dsfsdfsdf yayayay 
   hello world
- yay still contiguous bulleting ( no added/required empty line while editing, or displayed in the resulting markdown)

It seems to work here using `<br />` although that is kinda painful compared to being able to space + `-` + space + ```` ``` ```` + paste multi-line text + ```` ``` ```` or something.

I tried both `<br />` and `<br/>`

Is there a way I can do that on Trello?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works you need to edit it like in the screenshots attached with "-" in front of every item you want to create

[image: Editor]

[image: How it works]